# Problema con ORDER BY : DESC

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Buenas, tengo el siguiente problema, que tengo una red social donde la gente puede publicar cosas y  enviar mensajes, la cosa esta en que al hacer un `select` de todas las publicaciones y mostrarlas el `order by UNIX_TIMESTAMP (data) DESC` no me funciona, no me las ordena, lo curioso es que lo logré hacer pero con otra BBDD, que casualmente no encuentro.

BBDD:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `publicacions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `contingut` text NOT NULL,
  `usuari` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `imagen` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data` datetime NOT NULL
```

SQL :

```
$sql = "select usuaris.nom, usuaris.cognom, publicacions.contingut from usuaris, publicacions where usuaris.id = publicacions.usuari order by UNIX_TIMESTAMP (data) DESC;";
```

Comment: deberías hacer print agregando `UNIX_TIMESTAMP (data) ` como columna para ver qué valores está entregando...dudo mucho que simplemente no esté ordenando

Comment: Porque no haces el orderby directamente sobre data? Sin la funcion UNIX_TIMESTAMP.

Comment: `data` es un campo solo de la tabla `publicacions`?

Comment: Igual el problema te viene dado por la forma de unir las tablas, puedes probar a hacerlo con un `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Debes considerar lo que dice [la doc de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) al usar `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`, sobre todo para ordenar o comparar valores. Como dice la respuesta, no creo que sea necesario usar esta función en tu consulta, menos aún si la columna `data` no es del tipo `timestamp`, columna que por cierto yo tendría _miedo_ de llamarla `data`, algo muy muy parecido a una palabra reservada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No veo la necesidad de usar **UNIX_TIMESTAMP**, el **DATETIME** puedes ordenarlo sin problemas mediante el **DESC**, y también lo que deberías usar es un **INNER JOIN**, así:

```
SELECT u.nom, u.cognom, p.contingut 
FROM publicacions as p
INNER JOIN usuaris as u
ON (u.id = p.usuari)
ORDER BY p.data DESC;
```

Espero te sirva mi respuesta, saludos.

Comment: Pero `data` no es un `int`

Answer (score 0):

Me gustaria ver el trace del error para tener una idea mas clara del problema, sin embargo en mi experiencia yo haria el query de la siguente forma:

Usar alias es una buena practica para querys grandes ya que te ayuda a mantener organizado el query.

```
$sql = "SELECT usuaris.nom, usuaris.cognom, publicacions.contingut FROM usuaris as u, publicacions as p WHERE u.id = p.usuari ORDER BY nombre_tabla.nombre_columa DESC";
```